# Error creating bean with name : Unsatisfied dependency expressed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm getting this error while trying to start my app. I've looked at many similar problems and topics but none seems to help me.

> Error creating bean with name 'databaseManager': Unsatisfied dependency 
>       expressed through field 'articleRepo'; nested exception is 
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
>       qualifying bean of type 
>       'pl.dzejkobdevelopment.database.repositories.ArticleRepo' available: 
>       expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency 
>       annotations: 
>       {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

```
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepo extends CrudRepository<Article, Long> {
}
```

and...

```
@Service
public class DatabaseManager {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleRepo articleRepo;
    @Autowired
    private CommentRepo commentRepo;
    @Autowired
    private TagRepo tagRepo;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    public void addArticle(Article article){
        article.getTags().forEach(tag ->addTag(tag));
        articleRepo.save(article);
    }

    public List<Comment> findComments(User user){
        return commentRepo.findByCommentAuthor(user);
    }

    private void addTag(Tag tag){
        tagRepo.save(tag);
    }


}
```

and...

```
@Configuration
//@ComponentScan(basePackages="pl.dzejkobdevelopment.database.repositories")
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebsiteProporties websiteProporties(){
        return new WebsiteProporties();
    }
    @Bean
    public StorageProperties storageProporties(){ return new StorageProperties();}
    @Bean
    public DatabaseManager databaseManager(){ return new DatabaseManager();}

    }
}
```

Uncommenting `ComponentScan` doesn't help.

**EDIT**
Changeing `ComponentScan` for `EnableJpaRepositories` gives this error:

> Error creating bean with name 'databaseManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'articleRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'articleRepo': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#14a1d6d' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#14a1d6d': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("pl.dzejkobdevelopment.database.repositories")
```

instead of ComponentScan.

Comment: That's great - the initial problem is solved. Now you have to configure JPA.

Comment: Something like this:

  @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        // set properties
        return emf;
    }

Comment: Hmmm, okay but I'm using Spring Boot. I thought it is already configured. I have all db proporties (username, password etc.) in application.configuration file. And it works cause I can add entities with CommandLineRunner

Comment: If you want to use SpringBoot, you need to tell Spring to use it :) You may want to add more annotaions to your configuration class: `@SpringBootApplication` or at least `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.